# How can I allow http and https versions of my site, but make it default to https?

Tags: apache, https

I just added https support to a site I own. Normally I would add a couple lines to my .htaccess file to redirect http to https, but in this case I want to leave both accessible. (Why? It has user data stored in IndexedDB and http/https versions of the same site cannot access the same database, so I want to let users keep using the old http version with their old data in it.)

That works fine, except one thing. When a user types "example.com" into his browser, it takes him to "http://example.com". To get the https version, you need to explicitly type "https://example.com". Is there any way to swap that behavior, so https is the default unless you explicitly ask for http?

Comment: All you need is a redirect.  The details will vary depending on your choice of web server (e.g. Apache vs. IIS).  For Apache, you can use [.htaccess](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-redirect-http-to-https-using-htaccess/) Your ISP can make the process transparent.  For example: https://www.godaddy.com/help/redirect-http-to-https-automatically-8828.  There's only ONE site (not "different versions"), accessed by either/both of two PROTOCOLS (http vs. https).,

Comment: Thanks but that's not quite what my question is about, I don't want to redirect http to https, I just want the default (when no protocol is specified by the user typing in his browser URL bar) to be https.

Comment: "To get the https version, you need to explicitly type "https://example.com" - that's simply WRONG.  1) If the redirect is working properly, the user does NOT need to type "https".  2) If there's no redirect - that's your fault. 3) If you want some "magic" to force the browser to default to "https" instead of  "http": https://www.ghacks.net/2021/01/04/chrome-will-soon-try-https-first-when-a-user-types-an-address-in-the-browser/

Comment: Thanks. My question is basically if there is some way to trick that magic into happening now, for all users in all browsers. I am aware that there's no global http/https redirect - that's on purpose, as I wrote in the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default protocol is a choice of the browser, not your server. Just wait a bit, one of the next versions of Chrome / Chromium will [change the default](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1141691) and I expect others to follow suit.

(that makes this question "not programming related" though)